# Internal run time css disturbing page default CSS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to bind html in my angularjs code.

```
<div class="preview-container" slimscroll="{height: '', color: '#00AAFF', alwaysVisible: 'true'}">
    <div ng-bind-html='previewHtml' class="preview-container"></div>
</div>
```

The value for **previewHtml** is retrieved from server consist of its own css style.
The internal css of **previewHtml** is causing disturbance in the default css of host page.

the content that retrieved from server for previewHtml will look something like this.

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"> -->
    <style type="text/css">
       ...some value 
    </style>
    <table > 
        ...some value  
    </table>
    </div>
```

Is there any way to avoid this disturbance caused by internal/runtime css

Answer (score 0):

The best way to assure it, is using inline style, which is more specific than style inside the `<style>` tag.

```
 <div style="your_preview_style: here;" slimscroll="{height: '', color: '#00AAFF', alwaysVisible: 'true'}">
    <div ng-bind-html='previewHtml' class="preview-container"></div>
 </div>
```

It is also recommended to use prefix in you css classes names, for example:

`appInitial-preview-container`

This may solve your problem without using inline styles.